# Magento 2: Static content signing

Tags: magento2, static-content

What is the use and benefit of **static content signing** in Magento 2 ? Is it recommended to disable it from backend ?

Answer (score 3):

It's best to keep Static Content Signing Enabled due to it's performance benefits.

You can read more about it on the Magento 2 DevDocs - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response. I understood. But I think in most cases such static sign didn't work. I need to disable it. Otherwise CSS, JS etc. are not loading in the frontend due to 404 error for those static files.

Comment: If you're receiving 404s on those files with Static Content Signing enabled then your web server isn't setup correctly. Refer to the sample .htaccess or NGINX config on the Magento 2 repo.

Comment: If you're able to confirm which web server you're using (NGINX/Apache) then I can help further.

Comment: I m using ngnix

Answer (score 2):

Static content signing is one of those Magento feature which solve the problem of browser cache on client side, for example if you have changed the css/image on a web page with same url, normally browser will cache it and in order for user to have the updated css/image, they need to clear their browser cache untill it expires. Magento solve this problem by invalidating the browser cache for static resources by adding a deployment version to the URL of static files.

So now each time if something is changed in the static files, Magento will change the url which will force browser to reload the updated css/image.

Comment: For SEO purposes this seems really bad. Google keeps crawling old signed files as it remembers old static paths from HTML of previous deployments. It's just wasting crawl budgets.